# Determine for which $p>0$ the double integral converges

Tags: multivariable-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I would appreciate help solving the double integral below. I have started the task but cannot complete it fully.

*Let $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb(R)^2:x^2+y^2 < 1\}$. Determine for which $p>0$ the double integral converges: $$\iint_D\frac{1}{(x^4+2x^3y+3x^2y^2+2xy^3+y^4)^p}.$$*

**My attempt:** My idea is to use polar coordinates, so I started by rewriting the expression in the denominator as follows $$(x^4+2x^3y+3x^2y^2+2xy^3+y^4)^p=(x^2+xy+y^2)^{2p}.$$ Then I can put in polar coordinates and get that $(r^2+r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)^{2p}=(r^2)^{2p}(1+\cos\theta\sin\theta)^{2p}$ which makes it possible to split the integral into the following $$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1+\cos\theta\sin\theta)^{2p}}d\theta\int_0^1\frac{r}{(r^2)^{2p}}dr.$$ For the second integral
I carried out the variable substitution $u=r^2$, $du=2r dr$ and got the value $\frac{1}{2-4p}$. But it is now when I have to find the value of the first integral that I get stuck.

I started by looking at trigonometric rewrites for $1+\cos\theta\sin\theta$ but found nothing that would facilitate the calculations. I also looked at whether you could employ $u=\cos\theta\sin\theta$, but then $du=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$ and that would not simplify the calculations either since I then need to divide with the expression.

I would be happy to receive tips on how I could solve this task. Maybe there is something obvious that I have missed but I have been looking at this for a while now so any suggestions are warmly welcomed!

Comment: The $r$ integer; only converges for $p<0$. I suspect the $\theta$ integral always converges when $p<0$ . You can show that it converges by just using the bounds $\frac 12 \le 1 + \cos \theta \sin\theta \le \frac 32$

Comment: The range that WW1 told comes from using the identity $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$.

Also, isn't $du=2rdr$?

Comment: @WW1 Why for $p<0$? Shouldn't it be for $p>1/2$ for the r integer?

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith Thank you for that information! Yes you are correct, it should be $du=2rdr$, I wrote that one wrong. I have edited that now!

Comment: @WW1 Sorry, I ment for $p<1/2$ and not greater than.

Comment: @kabin  $p < \frac 12$ is correct

Comment: @WW1 Great, thank you for your help!